# Linux: exclude specific file types when running "locate"

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, find

I'd like to configure [locate](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?locate+1) to always exclude specific file types.

For example, I would like to exclude ".pyc" ".class" "~" etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a duplicate question from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/50040/how-can-i-make-locate-updatedb-ignore-certain-file-extensions):

In updatedb.conf, uncomment the PRUNENAMES line and add the extension .pyc. On my Ubuntu system by default it reads:

```
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
```

Change it to

```
PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn .pyc"
```

Comment: Caveat this only works for directory names, not file names.

Answer (score 1):

look at `/etc/updatedb.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Hideous hack though it may be, you could always use grep:

locate foo | grep -v ".pyc$" | grep -v ".class$"

and chain as necessary.